# Google Map API - Get coordinates from multiple addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have a database with 400.000+ postal addresses and I would like to get the coordinates for each of them.
I tried to design a simple script who go through each records and make a request to the Google Map API to get the coordinates. But it takes forever, as for every record, it has to wait the response from the API.

My question: is it possible to send an array of all my addresses (or at least a part of) to the API and get all the coordinates at once?

Answer (score 2):

If they are UK postcodes you can download the lat lng from here. 
I'm sure it's also possible to find the full postal address to with the lat, lng to to download for free or to purchase.

https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

Not the answer to your question, but maybe a solution for you?

Or here: http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php

Comment: Hi Ian, actually my addresses are in France, and it's not only ZIP code, it's full addresses, so I think it will be complicated to find such a file for all addresses in France ! :)

Comment: That looks really interesting ! I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the Google API provides such things as they bill per request. Perhaps they offer this features but it will be probably not free.

But as you mentions the data is limited to France, I think the best way is to use the [official French government API](https://geo.api.gouv.fr/adresse) which seems to be free.
As your question was posted 4 years ago, this French site was probably not existing.

In their documentation they offer the possibility to send a CSV of maximum 50Mb at once (`/search/csv/` in the above link).

Example:

1. Take their `search.csv` example:

```
nom,adresse,postcode,city
École Claude Déruet,6 Rue Albert 1er,54600,Villers-lès-Nancy
École Gilberte Monne,6 Rue d'Aquitaine,54500,Vandœuvre-lès-Nancy
École maternelle Victor Hugo,31 Rue d'Arbois,54180,Heillecourt
École maternelle Buffon,1 bis Rue de la Papeterie,54250,Champigneulles
```

2. execute the Curl request:

```
curl -X POST -F data=@search.csv https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/
```

You can also restrict the result to the fields you need like only longitude and latitude:

```
curl -X POST -F data=@search.csv https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/ -F result_columns=longitude -F result_columns=latitude
```

The limitation are:

```
2 requêtes simultanées par IP pour le géocodage de masse (maximum 50 Mo par envoi de fichier pour le géocodage direct, 6 Mo pour le géocodage inversé).
```

Which means 2 simultaneous query from the same IP for the CSV search.

Some links are:

- [National data](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/donnees-nationales)
- [Licensing](https://www.etalab.gouv.fr/licence-ouverte-open-licence)